# Titanium TableView data row adding custom background

Tags: titanium, row, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

i get data from my wordpress categories in titanium mobile app, i have 5 categories how to set background this 5 row ?
This My Categories JS

```
$.init = function() {

var rows = [];  
 getCategories(function(_data) {

    for (var x = 0; x < _data.length; x++) {

        rows.push(Alloy.createController('category-item', {
            data : _data[x]
        }).getView());

    }

    $.categories_table.setData(rows);

    APP.Loading.hide();
    });
```

This category-item

```
$.c_title.text = args.data.name  ; 
$.c_counts.text = args.data.count  ; 
$.row.Item = args.data;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$.row` is the `Ti.UI.TableViewRow` object, you'd do:

`$.row.backgroundImage = args.data.variableHoldingImagePath;`

Comment: thnx for replies how to set variableHoldingImagePath not any binding image can i local binding and can i use this code row1 row2 ? ?

Comment: You can set an URI to a remote image, you can also specify a local image.
Local image should be in assets folder, then simply set the path of the image (with assets/[platform] as the root folder).  
Ex: `$.row.backgroundImage = '/images/row.png'`

Comment: now can i added background image but how to can add seperatly row ex row1 image1.png row2 image.2 png
$.row.backgroundImage = '/images/row.png'
$.row2.backgroundImage = '/images/row2.png'
Possible ?
http://i.hizliresim.com/XoX315.png

Comment: Well, make sure args.data has the right path for each row. You could do this in the for() loop in your first code block.